# How do you query posts from more than one author in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do you query posts from more than one author in Wordpress?

something like: 
`query_posts('author=9,10&post_status=publish&orderby=date')`

This is not working though.

Answer (score 2):

According to this documentation there is no official support: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts - under "Author Parameters" heading.

However, digging into the source code reveals otherwise: http://wordpress.taragana.net/nav.html?wp-includes/classes.php.html#query_posts.

```
$author_array = preg_split('/[,\s]+/', $q['author']);
for ($i = 1; $i < (count($author_array)); $i = $i + 1) {
    $whichauthor .= ' '.$andor.' post_author '.$eq.' '.intval($author_array[$i]);
}
$whichauthor .= ')';
```

To see if your comma-separated list is being used correctly I would go ahead and start throwing debug lines into the `WP_Query::get_posts()` function. For example, what is the final value of `$whichauthor`?

Comment: ok, well dumb mistake. I thought I had selected that page template but did not.  The original 
query_posts('author=9,10&post_status=publish&orderby=date') 
did work just fine for the record.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the right way to do it :

```
function yclads_posts_where_followed_authors($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    $authors_ids = array(0,1,2,3);//array of authors IDs

    if (count($authors_ids) > 0) 
    {
         $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_author IN(' . implode (',',$authors_ids) . ') ';
    }
    else 
    {
        $where .= ' AND 1=2'; //do not return results
    }
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where_filter_authors');
```

Answer (score 0):

The query_posts() function was only meant to support querying one author at a time.  If you want to display multiple authors, I suggest trying one of the following:

1. Create your own custom query to include multiple author IDs.  You can use $wpdb->query() to run just about any SQL statement on the database, so you can definitely get a list of all posts by multiple authors, it just takes more work.
2. The second option is to group your posts by author and run a separate WordPress loop for each author ID.  This breaks your content up somewhat, but you could preface each section with a short author bio.  There's example code on [this site](http://wpthemesupport.com/display-multiple-authors-in-wordpress).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect for my needs.  Simple solution #2.

Comment: scratch that, it didn't quite work.  The page is just getting hung up now.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?  There's no reason a multiple loop solution should hang the page.

Answer (score 0):

This slightly different loop will work mutliple times on a page or post with a different query parameters:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('author=9&post_status=publish&orderby=date'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```